# Any way to accept any type of schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have this schema, I am expecting only 1 'any' schema in the dataRecord property below. I am also expecting that dataRecord property should only hold schemas. At this moment we only have 2 sub schemas which we reference in dataRecord property. In the future we expect more schemas to add like for example test2, test3 and so on. I want to avoid editing the below schema to add more $ref to dataRecord property. Is there a way to achieve this without adding more references to dataRecord property and at the same time to make sure there is always 1 schema provided. Any help would be appreciated.

```
{
 "id": "http://anysiteaddress",
 "type": "object",
 "properties": {
 "recordId": {
  "type": "string"
},
"dbOperationType": {
  "type": "string"
},
"schema": {
  "type": "string"
},
"schemaVersion": {
  "type": "string"
},
"utcTimeStamp": {
  "type": "string"
},
"dataRecord": {
  "oneOf" : [
    { "$ref": "test.json#/definitions/test"},
    { "$ref": "test1.json#/definitions/test1"}
    ]
}
},
"additionalProperties": false,
"required": [
"recordId",
"dbOperationType",
"schema",
"schemaVersion",
"utcTimeStamp",
"dataRecord"
 ]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the kind of thing you would like is to be able to reference a directory and have the `oneOf` include each schema found in that directory.  This is not something you can do with JSON Schema.  You are going to have to modify something to add a new schema.

You could create an additional schema for `dataRecord` and have your schema reference that new schema.  Then your schema doesn't need to change when you add a new schema, but you do have to change the dataRecord schema instead.

Your other option is to generate this part of the schema in code before it is served.  Depending on how you intend to use this schema, this may or may not be a good option.

Comment: for the first approach you mentioned to reference a directory. I am not sure how to do it, can you provide some example?

Comment: I didn't present that as an option.  I said it was "not something you could do with JSON Schema".  Sorry if that wasn't clear.